# How to import URLExtension so its available to all Views & Ascx (Asp.NET MVC 2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am using a extension class for pulling images, css, scripts etc.

In the UI layer, I have Master Pages, Views (aspx) and Partial Views (ascx). Is it required to Import `<%@ Import Namespace="Resorts.Web.Helpers" %>` inside each Master, View & Ascx? If I import inside Master, why can't my Views & Ascx automatically know about it? Am I doing it wrong way?

```
namespace Resorts.Web.Helpers
{
    public static class UrlHelperExtension
    {
        public static string Image(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
        {
            return helper.Content("~/Content/Images/" + fileName);
        }

        public static string Stylesheet(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
        {
            return helper.Content("~/Content/CSS/" + fileName);
        }

        public static string Script(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
        {
            return helper.Content("~/Scripts/" + fileName);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it available in all or most of your pages then using the import directive is indeed the wrong way to do it.

The way to add an available namespace is in your web.config file. There should be a section like:

```
<system.web>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
            <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Just add Resorts.Web.Helpers to the list of namespaces. You might need to rebuild your app or restart VS afterwards but this will now make your namespace available in masterpages, views and partials.